# Determine the orientation of an ESD protection chip

Tags: esd, integrated-circuit

I have an [ESD protection chip](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00161229.pdf) that has been unsoldered from my board, and for which we have lost the orientation. (I.e. we don't know where pin 1 is - the little dot has gone.)

Because of the symmetry of the IC's package, there are two possibilities for the orientation. Is it possible to use a voltmeter or scope to retrieve the orientation of this part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the diagram in the datasheet, this chip is 'just' a bunch of 5..7V zener diodes.

[image: ESDALC6V1-5P6]

If you use a low voltage (<5V) you can test the diodes. If your multimeter uses a low voltage you could even use it to measure the resistance: pins 1-2 should have a low resistance in at least one direction, much lower than 4-5.

But the fact that the dot has disappeared makes me wonder whether the chip should still be trusted. Note that this is a protection chip, so soldering it in and checking that the device works is no guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Pin 2 connects to the anodes of the diodes,

[image]

so you should measure a 1 V drop maximum(*) from pin 2 to any of the other pins. If you have the device reversed and would test this from pin 5 instead you'll need to overcome the diode's breakdown voltage of minimum 6.1 V first. So if you apply 3 V (with a series resistor) you'll have current from pin 2 to any other, but not from any of the other pins.

(*) Forward and breakdown voltage are listed in table 2 on page 2 of the datasheet.